# Graph API - Getting Insufficient privileges in microsoft graph console application

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Code I am using in console application:

```
public static string GetAccessToken()
{
    // Create the authentication context (ADAL) 
    //Authority is something like https://login.microsoftonline.com/xyz.com
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);  

    // Get the access token
    var credentials = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);

    //Graph Resource https://graph.microsoft.com/
    var authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphResource, credentials);  

    var accessToken = authenticationResult.Result.AccessToken;
    return accessToken;  //we are getting access token here
}

public static HttpClient GetHttpClient(string accessToken)
{
    // Create the HTTP client with the access token
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
        accessToken);
    return httpClient;
}

public static async Task MakeRequest()
{
    // Get an access token and configure the HttpClient
    var accessToken = GetAccessToken();
    var httpClient = GetHttpClient(accessToken);

    var uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/abc@xyz.com/";

    // Get the current user (to extract the mail address)
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);


    //var user = await MailClient.GetUserAsync(httpClient);   //this is also not working
    // Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);


    if (response.Content != null)
    {
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
}
```

In responseString we are getting:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "code":"Authorization_RequestDenied",
      "message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
      "innerError":{  
         "request-id":"79267719-b160-4817-a200-xxxxxxxxxx",
         "date":"2018-01-14T11:00:00"
      }
   }
}
```

Permission which we have in app permissions is as below:
[image]

In delegated permissions we have read all user full profiles permission but not in application permissions.

Query: Is it actually permission issue or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using User.Read.All (Read all users' full profile) or User.ReadBasic.All (Read all users' basic profile) - see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference for details on permissions.

Setting these permissions only says "these are the permissions that my app **requires**".  It doesn't actually grant any permissions - you need to explicitly grant the permissions or get a customer to consent.  If this is for your own tenant, you can click on the "Grant permissions" button in the Azure portal.  Then try the app again.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications for more details on configuring permissions, granting permissions and consent.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Dan..i will check and update here. Do you see any problem in our code..anything which we are not doing right?

Comment: @dan-kershaw-msft Please reply on my above query

Comment: Read All users' full profiles was required in application permissions section.In delegated permissions we had read all user full profiles permission but we were missing Read All users' full profiles in application permissions

Comment: Is the issue resolved?  Looks like there might have been some confusion between application and delegated permissions?  If you are using the client credentials flow, then only the application permissions are relevant - setting delegated permissions will have no effect.